# Burninate tag: programming

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The only benefit I could see for this tag is that it would help make off-topic questions easier to identify and close/migrate. Why not just a "close-me" or "bad-question" tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. Of the five questions filed under [programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming), only one is open (with three close votes). Questions that do not qualify for [programming-languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) are most likely offtopic. Therefore, the tag should be shot on sight.

Comment: Wow, have you read the tag description for programming? It basically says "programming is off-topic here". Am I the only one who got a chuckle, or is Kaveh or Gilles or somebody making gag tags? Is it you?

Comment: @Patrick87: [It was Kaveh](http://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/1022/revisions). It might actually be a good idea to fend off offtopic question if people who want to use the tag are hit by the excerpt.

Comment: The tag will naturally go away when the questions in this tag are deleted.